# I was told this is a Sedum succulent. If so, what kind? There are so many!

Tags: identification, succulents, sedum

I have been told this is a sedum succulent. But what kind of sedum? I want to know to find out if it is indigenous in Cape Town. [image]

[image]

Comment: It is definitely a Sedum but yours is a bit diminished and tough to tell form and color.  You need to make sure you don't water too much.  They store their own water and are extremely sensitive to wet feet.  Don't water so much that the water drains out of the pot.  A pot half that height would be best.  Water only when the whole pot is light to lift.  Is this potting soil or some other mixture?  Someone might be able to tell you the species and variety so wait until others have viewed your plant, okay?  Have you added any fertilizer?  What type?

Answer (score 2):

It could be Crassula tetragona rather than a Sedum, which is a South African native, but because it's spindly with few leaves, it is hard to be certain, image here https://www.bigstockphoto.com/image-134308073/stock-photo-closeup-of-miniature-pine-tree%2C-crassula-tetragona%2C-succulent-plant-with-woody-stem-grown-in-south-australia